# Sudoku Game: How to test code that includes reading a binary file

Tags: c

I am assigned to create a Sudoku game, where the **9x9** table should take the first settings from a binary file. Every registry contains **3** bytes with this format:

- **1st** byte is **row**
- **2nd** byte is **column**
- **3rd** byte is the **number** that we wish to enter, in the combination above

for example: 069

On the 1st row and 7th column we put number 9.

My question here is, how should I test the code(?) when my only choice for example is me creating a binary file and reading it again.

Comment: well, I guess you're going to end up writing a sudoku problem editor :-) ... since all your data is stored in 3 byte records, should not be that hard.   

You could also create a simple reader that reads a `row` `col` `val` one line at a time and stores them in the proper format on disk

Comment: Why does the file need to be binary?  Even if you had 81 entries at 3 digits and a newline each, it is a tiny little file — and you won't have anything like 81 entries in it.  So, you should aim to use a text file.  If you think you must use a binary file, you test by creating a program that takes a text file and creates the binary file.  How big is each item in the binary file — 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes?  And if it's one byte, is it encoded as digit values in the range 48..57 (`'0'`..`'9'`), or as byte values (`'\000'`..`'\011'` — or `'\x0'`..`'\x9'`)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think it has to be binary because it's an assignment :P and it's probably a single byte so that it can be easily verified by a TA :P

Comment: The assignment has to use a binary file with no exceptions. After the insertion, the program uses recursion to solve the puzzle. So, the number of the records are unknown.

Comment: Just because the finished program outputs binary does not mean you can't output text to the console while you are developing it.  And to check the final binary output, just open it in a hex editor.

Comment: @paddy I'l try it. Thanks.

Comment: I think the simplest way to load the data in, is to load the contents of the file into a buffer of appropriate size, in this case it seemingly is 9 * 9 * 3 bytes. Define a packed struct with three unsigned char members: x, y, and value. Cast the buffer to a pointer to this type, and you can simply print out the values. For testing purposes, do the same but in reverse, and read it back out. Verify with a hex editor if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

First, what's so bad about creating your own repository of test files? You can even write a program in bash or something to run your sudoku game on all of your input files automatically to check if your code still works.

If you are working with `FILE*` pointers, though, you can likely use `fmemopen` in test code to create an in-memory stream that you can use with `fread`, etc.

If you are working with `fd`s, you can do something similar with `pipe`. Write into one end, read from the other.